# Somewhy the program always returns 'false'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Why does this code always return 'false' and activates the goto even when I type a digit? Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

```
char userValue = '4';
auto h = true;
tryAgain:
std::cout << "Please type a digit: ";
std::cin >> userValue;

switch (userValue) {
case '0':
case '1':
case '2':
case '3':
case '4':
case '5':
case '6':
case '7':
case '8':
case '9':
    h = true;
default:
    h = false;
}

switch (h) {
case true:
    std::cout << "This character is a digit.";
case false:
    std::cout << "Wrong! Try again!" << std::endl;
    goto tryAgain;
}
```

Comment: Clang has a [warning option](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/558934c7b81f965d) for this.

Comment: Add break for each case

Comment: You've gotten the solution to this particular problem. The general solution is to use a debugger, that would have let you see what was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to break out of the case if it has been processed.
That way it will fall through the cases and handle the `false` case after the `true` case has been handled.

```
switch (h) {
case true:
    std::cout << "This character is a digit.";
break;
case false:
    std::cout << "Wrong! Try again!" << std::endl;
    goto tryAgain;

    //not necessarily needed because goto leaves the scope anyway.
    //break;
}
```

The same issue here, break if you wan't to stop the fallthrough:

```
switch (userValue) {
case '0':
case '1':
case '2':
case '3':
case '4':
case '5':
case '6':
case '7':
case '8':
case '9':
    h = true;
    break;

default:
    h = false;
    break;
}
```